# Difference between 었어 and 였어

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between 었어 and 였어? Does it have anything to do with the ending sound of the word being conjugated? When should I use which one?

Comment: it changes the meaning of some verbs; 죽었어 = I died. 죽였어 = I killed it. 먹었어 = I ate it. 먹였어 = I fed it. 굴렀어 = I rolled. 굴렸어 = I rolled it.

Comment: What about 아니었어요 and 아니였어요? Which is correct?

Comment: `였어` is a shorthand for `ㅣ었어`. `아니었어요` `아니였어요` both are correct but they have different meanings. 아니었어 = 아니다(verb) + `었어` / 아니였어 = 아니(noun) + `ㅣ었어`

Comment: 내가 아니었어요 = It wasn't me. / 내가 아니였어요 = I was '아니'.

Answer (score 0):

The first “였다” is “이었다"'s abbreviations.

Noun: noun which has “받침” -이었다(었다)
noun which doesn't have “받침” -였다

verb: behind verb which is “past tense” (except for ㅏ, ㅓ) -었다
verb which attach(use)”~하다”,”하다” -였다